# Which functions.php file to use

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written some code on my WP server to expose some REST endpoints related to the Paid Member Subscriptions plugin. The functions are currently located in `mysite/wp-content/plugins/paid-member-subscriptions/includes/functions-member.php`, which is a file that was already there when I went poking around. The functions work great.

I wanted to keep my code a little more organized, so I tried putting these functions in a new `functions.php` file in the same folder, and also tried a `functions-tuz.php` file (to identify them as mine). The functions appear to be ignored from both of these locations.

There are about a dozen `functions-xxx` files in this folder with various names. I would imagine I could create another.

But I don't really know anything about WP. So, is there a way to put my functions in another file?

Here are the functions, if that matters (which I imagine it doesn't)

```php
add_filter("wcra_members_callback" , "wcra_members_callback_handler");
function wcra_members_callback_handler($param) {
    if ( $param['id'] ) {
        return pms_get_member( $param['id'] );  // <-- contains less useful info
    } else {
        return pms_get_members();
    }
}

add_filter("wcra_create_member_callback" , "wcra_create_member_callback_handler");
function wcra_create_member_callback_handler($param) {
    if ( !$param['user_id'] )
        return ("Please provide a user_id parameter."); // should be an ERROR
    if ( !$param['member_type'] )
        return ("Please provide a member_type parameter."); // should be an ERROR

    $user_id =  $param['user_id'] ;
    $member_type = $param['member_type'];

    $member = pms_get_member($user_id);

    if ( $member->is_member() )
        return ("This member is already registered. How did you get here anyway?"); // should be an ERROR

    $subscription_plan_id;
    switch ($member_type) {
        case 'provider': $subscription_plan_id = 986; break;
        case 'user': $subscription_plan_id = 988; break;
        default: return ("Invalid member type paramter"); // should be an ERROR
    }
    $start_date = date("Y/m/d");
    $end_date = $start_date + 1000;

    $result = $member->add_subscription($subscription_plan_id, $start_date, $end_date, 'active');

    return ($result == 1 ? pms_get_member($user_id): "Add subscription attempt failed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your theme's functions.php in `mysite/wp-content/themes/your-theme`

Or if you want to `functions-tuz.php` in your mentioned directory then add this line

`require 'functions-tuz.php';`

to one of the preinstalled PHP files e.g. `functions-member.php`